# Passing nested json argument variable as key to JQ json library

Tags: shell, arguments, expression, jq

I have two JSON files that I am passing to the jq object, check below:

Create.json

```
{
    "email_notifications": {
        "on_failure": "_"
    },
    "name": "_",
    "schedule": {
        "quartz_cron_expression": "_",
        "timezone_id": "Europe/Amsterdam",
        "pause_status": "_"
    }
}
```

Update.json

```
{
    "job_id": "_",
    "new_settings": {
        "email_notifications": {
            "on_failure": "_"
        },
        "name": "_",
        "schedule": {
            "quartz_cron_expression": "_",
            "timezone_id": "Europe/Amsterdam",
            "pause_status": "_"
        }
}
```

for Create.json i can use below expression:

```
TEMPLATE=`cat $FILE | jq
--arg _parent "$PARENT"
--arg _job_name "$JOB_NAME"
' ( . | .name ) |= $_job_name
| ( . | .schedule.pause_status) |= $_parent'
`
```

for Update.json I need to use the expression to include the parent key name:

```
TEMPLATE=`cat $FILE | jq
    --arg _parent "$PARENT"
    --arg _job_name "$JOB_NAME"
    ' ( .["new_settings"] | .name ) |= $_job_name
    | ( .["new_settings"] | .schedule.pause_status) |= $_parent'
```

To handle this I have used if else in the expression and it works perfectly:
( if .job_id? then .["new_settings"] else . end | .name ) |= $_job_name

but I want to pass the initial part as an argument, but it doesn't work and gives a syntax error. How can i make it dynamic that an argument becomes an expression on runtime when passed:

```
Filter="." OR Filter=".["new_settings"]"
TEMPLATE=`cat $FILE | jq
    --arg filter "$Filter"
    --arg _parent "$PARENT"
    --arg _job_name "$JOB_NAME"
    ' ( $filter | .name ) |= $_job_name
    | ( $filter | .schedule.pause_status) |= $_parent'
```

Comment: Why all the `stuff | .stuff`? Just `.[$filter].name |= $_job_name`, no?

Comment: How can this work for both files? Update.json has "new_settings", but Create.json doesn't have this. so how .[$filter] will be justified here?

Comment: You cannot pass a(nother) jq filter as an argument but you can construct the (one) filter using shell variables. And you can pass json content using parameter `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.

Comment: what about just `--arg filter 1_or_0 'if $filter == "0" . else .["new_settings"] end | ..`? You could always just do `' ( '"$Filter"' ...`

Comment: I don't want to use if else, I have already implemented this approach, I want my argument to take the place on runtime if its a . or .["new_settings"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# --arg root_path ""
# --arg root_path "new_settings"

getpath( $root_path | split(".") ) |= (
   .name                  = $_job_name |
   .schedule.pause_status = $_parent
)
```

---

The argument shouldn't be a piece of jq code. It would be a bad practice to accept a piece of jq code to pass to `eval`. But `jq` doesn't even have `eval`, so it's not even an option.

We could provide a path using a JSON array.

```
# --argjson root_path '[]'
# --argjson root_path '["new_settings"]'

getpath($root_path)
```

But a dot-separated path is much nicer.

```
# --arg root_path ""
# --arg root_path "new_settings"

getpath( $root_path | split(".") )                           # Supports objects
getpath( $root_path | split(".") | map( tonumber? // . ) )   # Supports objects & arrays
```

This gives us something like this:

```
getpath( $root_path | split(".") ) as $root |
( $root | .name                  ) |= $_job_name |
( $root | .schedule.pause_status ) |= $_parent
```

Except there's no point in using `$root` twice.

```
getpath( $root_path | split(".") ) as $root |
$root |= (
   .name                  |= $_job_name |
   .schedule.pause_status |= $_parent
)
```

or just

```
getpath( $root_path | split(".") ) |= (
   .name                  |= $_job_name |
   .schedule.pause_status |= $_parent
)
```

The only difference between `=` and `|=` is the context (`.`) provided to the right-hand side. The two previously-existing `|=` can therefore be simplified to `=`.

```
getpath( $root_path | split(".") ) |= (
   .name                  = $_job_name |
   .schedule.pause_status = $_parent
)
```

[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/KL3Qs8MSve) `Create.json`
[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/9hPne5kkyS) `Update.json`

Comment: What is the difference? = and |=

Comment: @shzyincu I made a proper Q&A of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69740318/589924)

Comment: below does not work when the array is used:
https://jqplay.org/s/Uy1VSpzkkx

Comment: @shzyincu, [This part](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/a8224b8cc30fb4870ca5cfdf344d57ec) looks wrong. It's probably missing parens. Comments are not the place to post new questions